# How do I implement an ADO.NET provider for SharePoint compatible with EF?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ado.net

I am trying to start a personal open source project of mine, which I believe might be useful for the community.
But I am trying to get some really useful and specific information on how to do (as the title implies) an ADO.NET provider to access some SharePoint objects. I believe this one could be really useful on Web API and Interoperability scenarios to create some mobile apps integrated to Office365 and on-premise SharePoint.
I have searched over the Internet (to my limited imagination) but found only how to implement and use ADO.NET provider but nothing that helped me on the theory of creating one.

Comment: I'd recomment to have a look at the `SPMetal` documentation: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538255(v=office.14).aspx) It's a command line tool which generates `LINQ-to-SharePoint entity classes` for use in `C#`. The documentation might help a lot in how to build your structures, then you can take it a step further and make it generic (given a connection to SharePoint, generate the classes for all existing objects automatically, etc.)

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh Thanks for the pointer (I am reading such solution now), could you add to it by how it could be to "generate the classes for all existing objects automatically"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am also wondering how close/far the code generated by SPMetal is from a real ADO.NET provider.

Comment: Well if you build an ADO.NET provider, I thought you might want to take it a step further and provide some mechanisms available in e.g. Entity Framework. Like you connect to a database in Visual Studio, and you can import all tables to auto-generate entities. You could create automations which allow the developer to connect to a SharePoint, pick some lists and your provider will generate the entities. Especially since you pointed out EF compatibility in your question, so you probably need entities for the use with LINQ.